# Trying to regex a string with backslashes and quotes

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to regex a string in csharp. I am expecting to pass a string with the following format:

```
<%=Application(\"DisplayName\")%>
```

and get back:

```
DisplayName
```

I am using the regex class to accomplish this:

```
var text = "<%=Application(\"DisplayName\")%>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(<\%=Application[\>\(\)][\\][""](.*?)[\\][""][\>\(\)k]%\>)");
var v = regex.Match(text);
var s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

I am expecting `s` to contain the output string, but it is coming back as `""`. I tried building the regex string step by step, but I can't get the `\` or `"` to process correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So is the actual string `"<%=Application(\"DisplayName\")%>"` or `<%=Application("DisplayName")%>`?

Comment: I apologize about that I removed the quotes. It's the latter. I edited the question.

Comment: @EvanGertis I believe he is asking about the slashes with the surrounding quotes of `DisplayName`. Is the actual string `\"DisplayName\"` or are the slashes only there to escape the double quotes in your `text` string variable? Is your actual input `\"DisplayName\"` or `"DisplayName"`?

Comment: Ah I understand now. I just added variable text to the code snippet. Does that make sense now?

Comment: @EvanGertis Yes. Thank you. You're really close. I'll post an answer after I type it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = "<%=Application(\"DisplayName\")%>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(<%=Application[>()][""](.*?)[""][>()k]%>)");
var v = regex.Match(text);
var s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent solution!

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is very close. Since the backslashes are not actually a part of the string, rather only in the string to escape the double quotes, they need to be left out of the regex pattern. Notice I removed the `[\\]` from before both of the double quotes `[""]`.

Now, you expect `DisplayName` in `Group[1]`. Since Regex sticks the entire match in `Group[0]`, that made your outer capture group (whole pattern in parenthesis) the first actual capture group (Making `DisplayName` actually `Group[2]`). For best practice, I changed the outer capture group to be a non-capture group by adding `?:` to the open parenthesis. This ignores this full group and makes `DisplayName` `Group[1]`. Hope this helps.

**Full test code:**

```
var text = "<%=Application(\"DisplayName\")%>";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:<\%=Application[\>\(\)][""](.*?)[""][\>\(\)k]%\>)");
var v = regex.Match(text);
var s = v.Groups[1].ToString();
```